# SQL WHERE clause with current time

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, where-in

My SQL table looks like

```
Start_Time  Query
21:00:00    Exec plugin1;
21:02:00    Exec plugin2;
21:04:00    Exec plugin3;
```

When I run the below query, I get an empty result

```
SELECT Query
FROM [test].[dbo].[schedule]
WHERE Start_Time IN ( SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108));
```

I also tried

```
SELECT Query
FROM [test].[dbo].[schedule]
WHERE Start_Time IN (select cast(CAST(GETDATE() as time) as varchar(5)));
```

How to I get it to return `Query` if `Start_Time` equals my current system time.

I am trying to create an SSIS task that runs every minute and checks whether time is equal to current time(in HH:MM), if so it returns the query and further execution happens.

Note: Time is in 24 hours format.

Comment: Please explain what logic you want to implement.

Comment: I don't understand: what are the chances the current time is *equal* down to the millisecond? What do you expect to happen

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, it's extremely unlikely that the when the sql query executes, it is accurate down to the millisecond. So, if it could just match it down to minutes(HH:MM), I think that should work

Comment: You probably want something like `WHERE Start_Time BETWEEN TIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()), DATEPART(mi, GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0) AND DATEADD(mi, 1, TIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()), DATEPART(mi, GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0))`

Answer (score 1):

Change your subselect to this below since you're doing `VARCHAR(5)`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108)+':00'
```

Otherwise you could do this if you're looking for precision to the second.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)
```

Comment: Hey, this worked for me but I had a question, Is there a way we could add a condition which says if current time is within +2 minutes of start_time, return query(assuming my time intervals are larger e.g 30 mins or more)

Comment: @TNT Yes, you could change the whole `WHERE` clause to be `WHERE DATEDIFF(MI,start_time,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108)+':00') BETWEEN 0 AND 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT Query
FROM [schedule]
WHERE Start_Time = CONVERT(varchar(8),getdate(),8)
```